# Cannot instantiate a C++ class in Python using SWIG (Gets Attribute error)

Tags: python, c++, swig

I wanted to export C++ classes into Python, for which I created an C++ extension module using SWIG. From the documentation, I can see that classes can be exported using SWIG. I am able to create the class module for python successfully(_minimal.pyd). I can import the module in Python. However, I am not able to create an object of the class and I am getting Attribute error. Please find the code samples I have tried. Could anyone please help me?

```
//minimal.h
class minimal
{
private:
    static int num_instances;

public:
    minimal()
    {
        ++num_instances;
    }
    ~minimal()
    {
        --num_instances;
    }

    void print_num_instances();
};

//minimal.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "minimal.h"

int minimal::num_instances = 0;

void minimal::print_num_instances()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << this->num_instances << endl;
}

//minimal.i(interface file)
%module minimal

%{
#include "minimal.h"
%}

%include "minimal.h"

//python code used to run the module
import _minimal as m
m1=m.minimal()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SWIG generates `minimal_wrap.cxx` and `minimal.py`.  When you build the .cxx file into `_minimal.pyd`, you then `import minimal`, not `import _minimal`.

```
>>> import minimal
>>> x=minimal.minimal()
>>> x.print_num_instances()
1
>>> y=minimal.minimal()
>>> x.print_num_instances()
2
```

For reference see [36.2.1 Running SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Python.html#Python_nn4) In the SWIG Python documentation.  Quote:

> ...[Running swig -c++ -python] This creates two different files; a C/C++ source file example_wrap.c or example_wrap.cxx and a Python source file example.py. The generated C source file contains the low-level wrappers that need to be compiled and linked with the rest of your C/C++ application to create an extension module. The Python source file contains high-level support code. This is the file that you will import to use the module.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. But I couldn't import it as import minimal.It throws me error module not found. I am using Visual Studio 2015 and Python 3.6.5 Anaconda distribution.

Comment: @AparnaBose I guess you found it since you accepted the answer? :^)

Comment: Sir..could you tell me the compiler and python version used? Could that be any issue here? I could import and use a fibonacci function using import _modulename. But not classes.

Comment: No sir...your answer was valid as I wondered why we had to use underscore in compiler settings.

Comment: The _modulename.pyd file is not meant to be imported directly.  SWIG also generates `modulename.py` which in turn imports _modulename.pyd.  Most likely you built the _modulename.pyd but did not move the modulename.py file into the same directory with the .pyd.

Comment: Is that the way it is supposed to work? I didn't know that despite the research I had put in the google. Thanks a lot sir...I have been struggling with this the whole day. I had thought we use the .pyd directly as in the case of extending python with C/C++ using Cpython.

Comment: I will definitely try this in the morning and close the post :) Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @AparnaBose I added a reference to the docs talking about it.

Comment: @AparnaBose I was using Python 3.6 and VS2017, but VS2015 works as well with Python 3.6.

Comment: can we return numpy array from c++ extension module for python (SWIG), sir?

Comment: Can we work with multiple cpp and header files using SWIG? should we write .i file for each cpp file?